# Creating floors for an SVG floorplan converted to 3D and exported for use with Unity

Tags: unity, svg

My plan is to convert some floorplans into a map for a simple FPS game in Unity. The building I'm doing has three floors.

My workflow is as follows;

1. Import svg into Blender
2. Convert to mesh
3. Extrude walls to desired height (each path creates 4 vertexes creating nice, thick walls, each with an "inside" and "outside" face
4. Set each wall to a face for texturing inside Unity (normals are something I'm expecting problems with later on and am yet to deal with)
5. Import into Unity as OBJ

My problem is creating ceilings and floors. My idea was to simply select the vertices and hit F to fill with a plane, then extrude to the same thickness of the walls created with extruding from the SVG but this isn't a very exact process.

What would be the ideal way to achieve this? Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Needless to say I'm learning as I make this and am a n00b. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just add planes on top and bottom? Nice polycount, easy to hide in Unity if you need so.

Comment: Some screenshots to illustrate perhaps?

Comment: That was my idea but adding a plane to exactly match the walls seems to be beyond my capabilities.

Edit: obviously I can align it manually. I'm looking for some way to do it without me fiddling and visually aligning stuff.